# Django filtering the Q problem when is empty

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a problem filtering the data and showing the result in a table...

In my template I have some inputs that I send input values with ajax and then i get the value using `request.POST.get()` in my views. The problem appears when some fields are empty I receive an error "Cannot use None as a query value"

I want to do something like this but i cannot find a solution

ex. when the `request.POST.get` is empty that `Q` to be ignored 
Can anyone help me?
Thanks and sorry for my english

This is my code in my views.py

```
def api(request):
    a = request.POST.get('a')
    b = request.POST.get('b')
    c = request.POST.get('c')
    d = request.POST.get('d')
    e = request.POST.get('e')
    f = request.POST.get('f')
    g = request.POST.get('g')
    h = request.POST.get('h')
    raport = Test.objects.filter(
        Q(data_test__year__gte=a) &
        Q(data_test__year__lte=b) &
        Q(data_in__isnull=c) &
        Q(data_out__isnull=d) &
        Q(adress__fieldone=e) &
        Q(adress__fieldtwo=f) &
        Q(categoru=g) &
        Q(stare=h) &
        Q(medic=i)
    )
    serializer = TestSerializer(raport, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make a function that creates a [**`Q`**-object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) for only non-`None` values, like:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def q_without_none(**kwargs):
    return Q(**{k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v is not None})
```

or if you want to exclude the empty string as well:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def q_without_empty(**kwargs):
    return Q(**{k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v not in (None, '')})
```

Then we can construct the query like:

```
raport_pacient = Pacient.objects.filter(
    q_without_none(
        data_creare_pacient__year__gte=de_la,
        data_creare_pacient__year__lte=pana_la,
        data_iesire__isnull=iesit,
        data_deces__isnull=iesit,
        adresa_pacient__judet__nume_judet=judet,
        adresa_pacient__localitate__nume_localitate=localitate,
        categorie=categorie,
        stare_civila=stare_civila,
        medic=request.user.medic
    )
)
```

> **Note**: although not really your question, using a `JsonResponse` with `safe=False` is, like the name suggests, not very safe. There have been [exploits with lists for JSON](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/), so it is usually better to define a dictionary at the top level, for example like:
>
> ```
> return JsonResponse({'data': serializer.data})
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your method but doesn`t work. Ajax return a empty json

Comment: @Florin: that is because none of the `Pacient`s is matching the filter.

Comment: This is imposibile. In template I ve made a select option  which contains  Pacient fields data..

Comment: @Florin: can you edit your question with some (sample) data that you have entered in the database, togehter with the values with which you make the POST request (you can `print(request.POST)`). A possible explanation I think is that your user has a `request.user.medic`, so even if you do not pass POST data, you still do filtering.

Comment: i found the problem using one field for testing. The problem is that i must to fill all templates select option when i press button to send values with ajax. to work with your function. I need something which create Q() when a request.POST.get appear. I wish to understand me . i speak so bad english

Comment: @Florin: but that is happening here, you can still set `de_la = request.POST.get('de_la', default=1920)`. The idea is that you put the code in this answer *instead* of your `raport_pacient = Pacient.objects.filter(...)`, not instead of the processing of `request.POST.get(..)` parts.

Comment: return Q(**{k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v is not None and v is not "" }) . The solution was  to add " and v is not " " ' .Now selects from template works 
independent one of each other ... Thanks for helping me!!! .